# How to marshal a JAXB class instance as its superclass

Tags: java, marshalling, jaxb2

Is it possible to marshal a JAXB annotated class instance **as its superclass** (which is also a JAXB annotated class)?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BenamningTYPE", propOrder = {"benamningId"})
@XmlSeeAlso({MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE.class})
public class BenamningTYPE {
    ...
    @XmlElement(name = "BenamningId", required = true)
    protected IdentifierTYPE benamningId;
    ...
}
```

And the extended type:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE", propOrder = {"modifyDetails"})
public class MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE extends BenamningTYPE {
    ...
    @XmlElement(name = "ModifyDetails", required = true)
    protected ModifyDetailsTYPE modifyDetails;
    ...
}
```

So if this scenario:

```
BenamningTYPE b = new MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE();
...
```

Then I would like to marshal the *instance **b*** as *BenmaningTYPE* to get

```
<BenmaningTYPE>
    ...
</BenmaningTYPE>
```

And **NOT**:

```
<MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE>
    ...
</MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE>
```

How would this marshal invoke look like, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked it, but I'd try first:

```
new JAXBElement(new QName("BenmaningType"),
    BenManingTYPE.class, moreDetailedBenmaningTYPEInstance)
```

If you're generating classes from an XML Schema, check also the [copyable plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin). You could the copy data from an instance of `MoreDetailedBenamningTYPE` to the instance `BenmaningTYPE` and marshal that.

There are more possibilities, but they're a bit more complex.

Comment: The Copyable Plugin from the jaxb2-commons project was excacly what I wanted! I extended the JAXBCopyStrategy and added instanceof checks for each subclass and created a copy as its superclass, thank you!

Comment: BTW, I'm the author. Glad you've found it helpful.