# JAXB always marshalls extension - unable to get elements of a super type only

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, spring-ws, hyperjaxb

I'm stuck on a problem with **JAXB** / **Spring Web Services**. Below is the detailed description. I appreciate any suggestion that could help me to solve it. I can provide more if details if needed.

I am writing a web service that returns list of some entities. Spring WS is contract-first framework, so I started with the XSD similar to:

```
<element name="GetEntitiesRequest" type="Something"/>
<element name="GetEntitiesResponse" type="Entities"/>

<complexType name="Entities">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Entity" type="Entity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Entity">
    <sequence>
        (...)
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

It was working well. However, the "**Entity**" type begin to grow (there a lot of elements) which caused performance issues (there are many Entities in the response). So I decided to split "Entity" into two parts

1. Some general information that will be returned within the group response - **Entity**
2. More detailed information that will be returned in an another web service operation, specific for the entity - **EntityDetails**

So after the change the schema is as follows (**EntityDetails inherits from Entity**):

```
<element name="GetEntitiesRequest" type="Something"/>
<element name="GetEntitiesResponse" type="Entities"/>

<complexType name="Entities">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Entity" type="Entity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Entity">
    <sequence>
        (...)
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="GetEntityDetailsRequest" type="SomethingMore"/>
<element name="GetEntityDetailsResponse" type="EntityDetails"/>

<complexType name="EntityDetails">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="Entity">
            <sequence>
                (...)
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

JAXB (precisely: hyperjaxb3) generates classes for Entity (inheritance strategy = JOINED), EntityDetails, and Entities. Also, it creates the **ObjectFactory** with "createGetEntitiesResponse" method. I am using this method to marshall List retrieved through Hibernate from the **Entity** table.

### Theoretically, I should get list of "**Entity**" when sending "GetEntitiesRequest". However, I get list of "**EntityDetails**" instead.

If you read this form the beginning, you can imagine, that this what I wanted to avoid.

If you need more details, persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence (...)>
    <persistence-unit name="org.package">
        <class>org.package.Entity</class>
        <class>org.package.EntityDetails</class>
        <class>org.package.Entities</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I use Gradle for the build automation, and its jaxb plugin for the class generation:

```
jaxb 
{
    xsdDir = "src/main/webapp/schemas/messages"
    bindingsDir = "src/main/webapp/schemas/bindings"
    bindings = ["bindings.xjb"]
    xjc 
    {
        extension = true
        taskClassname = "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task"
        generatePackage = "org.package"
        args = ["-Xannotate", "-Xhyperjaxb3-jpa2", "-Xequals", "-XhashCode", "-XtoString"]
    }
}
```

currently, the bindings.xjb, beyond header, contains only:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <xjc:serializable/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

Comment: The types don't appear to match. There's a dangling "Something", and the complexType entries aren't showing any inheritance.

Comment: Corrected. EntityDetails inherits from Entity. Of course, these names are different in real - I forgot to change one of them.

Comment: If you use `createGetEntitiesResponse`, it accepts an object of the class `Entities`. The list it contains is a `List<Entity>`, and its elements could be objects of class `Entity` or of some subclass, i.e., `EntityDetails`. It depends on what is actually inserted. Are the objects taken from "the Entity table" (whatever that is) of class `Entity` or `EntityDetails??

Comment: Objects are taken from "Entity" table. Inheritance strategy for that table is JOINED, so EntityDetails columns are stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you get instances `Entity` from the database, NOT `EntityDetails`.

Try to create an isolated scenario, without the database. Just instantiate your `Entity`, fill it with something create the response and marshal it. See what happens.
You'll isolate the problem - either you're getting wrong instances from the database or the marshalling does not work as expected. Both is a bit hard to diagnose without seeing your code. Try to reduce your problem to one of the two I mentioned above.

Diclaimer: I'm the author of Hyperjaxb3.

Comment: You are right. JPA returns instances od EntityDetails, so I guess this is the issue. I tried to use @MappedSuperclass annotation on Entity, and it makes that no table is created for that parent class, but still I am not able to retrieve instances od EntityDetails **as** Entity objects. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Bartek I don't think so. The query will return the types you stored. If you stored EntityDetails, this is what you get. But if you just want to strip `EntityDetails` to `Entity`, this is possible with some plugin magic. You may be looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264422/how-to-marshal-a-jaxb-class-instance-as-its-superclass