# How to marshall object casted to his superclass in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have generated class BookingStructure that marshalling into

```
<BookingStructure>
    <elementBookingStructure />
</BookingStructure>
```

and inherited from him class Booking that marshalling into

```
<Booking>
    <elementBookignStructure />
    <elementBooking />
</Booking>
```

I need to marshall Booking like BookingStructure

```
<BookingStructure>
    <elementBookingStructure />
</BookingStructure>
```

How can I do this using javax.xml.bind? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I tried this

```
new JAXBElement<BookingStructure>(new QName("Booking"), BookingStructure.class, new Booking())
```

but the result is not what I needed

```
<BookingStructure>
    <elementBookignStructure />
    <elementBooking />
</BookingStructure>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to marshal a JAXB class instance as its superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264422/how-to-marshal-a-jaxb-class-instance-as-its-superclass)

Comment: It didn't help, maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: There are two advices there and the other one works definitely.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this using standard libraries, and not the 3rd?

Comment: For me personally it's 1st party. :) I don't know any other way, sorry. But maybe someone does (therefore comments and not an answer).